# Android C++ programming

Tags: c++, android

Is there any way to programm C++ applications on Android? I mean - using your Android device for programming and compiling projects.

Comment: ggogle first hit "android C++ programming": http://www.zdnet.com/blog/burnette/program-for-android-in-cc-with-the-native-development-kit-if-you-dare/1284

Comment: @Mitch - the linked article as well as likely most/all Google hits are about **programming C++ apps to run on Android**. Which has very little to do with OP's question, which is creating and compiling and running resulted compiled C++ code entirely on Android device (e.g. an Android program serving as IDE and/or C++ compiler)

Comment: @Mitch: Roman is asking about writing C++ on an Android phone, as opposed to writing C++ on your computer and compiling it to run on Android; your link, however, was about the latter.  (This is what DVK was saying, too.)

Comment: Probably likes to stab themselves in the privates with hot needles too.

Comment: Ah, I see. The reason I musunderstood is probably because I wouldn't do that in a million years!! Use a computer like everyone else

Comment: @Mitch - at some point back I managed to do my C homework and hacking on a 8088 laptop with no hard drive, 640k memory and 720k floppy for a disk storage (Turbo C++ 2.0 FTW!). Modern Android tablets pack LOTS more power and probably bigger screens too

Comment: @DVK: I'm sure its possible to extract ones own teeth as well, but I'm not going to recommended it!

Comment: @Mitch - Tom Sawyer did it :) http://www.enotes.com/tom-sawyer-text/chapter-vi-self-examination-dentistry

Comment: @Mitch - the point is, if someone HAS an android device and nothing else (say on vacation/flight/other travel), or an Android "PC" replacement (think 10" tablets), and they'd rather hack/learn C++ than surf porn, I'd rather encourage such person than criticize them.

Comment: @DVK: Really? "Delete Browsing History" ....

Answer (score 3):

It really quite depends on what you want to do.

If you just want to see the output of some C++ code, you could use some online compilers such as [Codepad](http://codepad.org/) or [Ideone](http://ideone.com/). Ideone also has an API, and there is an iPhone app called CodeToGo that uses it to provide the ability to "run" code in the app -- you could try to search or build something similar for Android.

Another possibility, although probably more complicated, is to install a full-blown linux distribution on your phone, for example, Debian (which has everything you'd need to install a compiler) -- there is a guide on how to do that [here](http://android-dls.com/wiki/index.php?title=Installing_Debian), and you can search for more on google.

Comment: There is also a IDEdroid  for Android (like CodeToGo for iPhone)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the scope of what you want to do.

At the very least, you can do small snippets of C++ code by typing them in and running in your browser via http://codepad.org/